# Can't connect to SQL Server from asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

Hi i want to publish my application in a IIS server.

First i create a database in my sql server and put all my needed data on it.

Then i update my `web.config` to use the new remote Database. Unfortunatly i get an error

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=IntranetDatabase;Data Source=SRVDEV2010\SRVDEV2010" />
```

Stacktrace :

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
```

I cheked if i can access database remotly. I create a `udl`file to verify my `connectionstring`, Here is the result.

[image]

I don't know why the udl file can connect but not my application. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Under which user is the Application Pool configured to run? you're using Windows Authentication which means your IIS App pool should be configured to run under a user that has access to the DB.

Comment: My application is under a pool that use NetworkService for Identity and i think the problem isn't there because i have another application under the same pool and it works great.

Comment: Well the UDL is running under your windows user, try to set the app pool to be your local windows user.

Comment: Can you give me more details?